# asp.net - how to set a session variable as soon as a new user visit any web page ?

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms

I have been developing a web application using asp.net web forms and need to access a counter variable globally. How to set this variable = 0 when new user visit any web page in my project ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook into the Session_Start event inside your global.asax file.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeGlobalVar = 0;
    //You can also set session variables specific to this session
    Session["someVar"] = "someValue";
}
```